Receiving only the first message client sends in golang websocket
I am making this clipboard app which uses WebSocket to transfer the content of the clipboard. Everything is working fine except for the client's messages; I am only able to receive the first message. Can you check where I am wrong? Here is my entire code.
I've tried everything. It works when I create a new socket for communication, but not in this one.
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/atotto/clipboard"
    "github.com/gen2brain/beeep"
    "github.com/getlantern/systray"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "github.com/skip2/go-qrcode"
)

var (
    clients               = make(map[*websocket.Conn]bool)
    clientsMutex          sync.Mutex
    lastClipboardContent  string
    isServerRunning       = false
    paused                = false // A flag to control pause/resume
    stopMonitoring        = make(chan bool)
    serverDone            = make(chan bool)
    serverShutdown        = make(chan bool) // Channel to signal server shutdown
    httpServer            *http.Server      // HTTP server instance
    notificationsEnabled  = true            // Flag to enable/disable notifications
    notificationsMenuItem *systray.MenuItem // Menu item to toggle notifications
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup // WaitGroup to track goroutines
var statusMenuItem *systray.MenuItem
var connectedDevicesMenuItem *systray.MenuItem

// Start the application
func main() {
    // Start the system tray and wait for it to exit
    go startSystemTray()
    // Block main goroutine to keep the application alive
    select {}
}

// Start the system tray
func startSystemTray() {
    systray.Run(onReady, onExit)
}

// Initialize system tray options
func onReady() {
    systray.SetIcon(getIcon())
    systray.SetTitle("Clipboard Sync")
    systray.SetTooltip("Clipboard Sync Server")

    // Add the new status items
    statusMenuItem = systray.AddMenuItem("Server Status: Paused", "Displays the current status of the server")
    connectedDevicesMenuItem = systray.AddMenuItem("Connected Devices: 0", "Displays the number of connected devices")

    // Add menu items
    startMenuItem := systray.AddMenuItem("Start sync", "Start the Clipboard Sync server")
    stopMenuItem := systray.AddMenuItem("Stop sync", "Stop the Clipboard Sync server")
    openQRMenuItem := systray.AddMenuItem("Open QR", "Open the QR code page in browser")

    // Add the toggle notifications button
    notificationsMenuItem = systray.AddMenuItem("Disable Notifications", "Toggle notifications on/off")

    // Add the exit button
    exitMenuItem := systray.AddMenuItem("Exit", "Exit the application")

    // Start the server on first launch
    startServer()

    // Initially disable the stop button and enable the start button based on server state
    updateMenuItemsState(startMenuItem, stopMenuItem)

    // Handle menu item clicks
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-startMenuItem.ClickedCh:
                fmt.Println("[INFO] Start menu clicked")
                if paused {
                    resumeServer() // Resume the server if it's paused
                } else {
                    startServer() // Start the server if it's not running
                }
                // Update the state of the menu items after starting the server
                updateMenuItemsState(startMenuItem, stopMenuItem)

            case <-stopMenuItem.ClickedCh:
                fmt.Println("[INFO] Stop menu clicked")
                stopServer() // Pause the server
                // Update the state of the menu items after stopping the server
                updateMenuItemsState(startMenuItem, stopMenuItem)

            case <-openQRMenuItem.ClickedCh:
                fmt.Println("[INFO] Open QR menu clicked")
                openQRCodePage()

            case <-exitMenuItem.ClickedCh:
                fmt.Println("[INFO] Exit menu clicked")
                os.Exit(0) // Exit the application
                return

            case <-notificationsMenuItem.ClickedCh:
                toggleNotifications() // Toggle notifications on or off
            }
        }
    }()
}

// Function to update the status in the menu
func updateServerStatus() {
    if paused {
        statusMenuItem.SetTitle("Server Status: Paused")
    } else if isServerRunning {
        statusMenuItem.SetTitle("Server Status: Running")
    } else {
        statusMenuItem.SetTitle("Server Status: Stopped")
    }
}

// Function to update the number of connected devices
func updateConnectedDevices() {
    clientsMutex.Lock()
    connectedDevicesMenuItem.SetTitle(fmt.Sprintf("Connected Devices: %d", len(clients)))
    clientsMutex.Unlock()
}

// Update the menu items' enabled/disabled state
func updateMenuItemsState(startMenuItem, stopMenuItem *systray.MenuItem) {
    if paused {
        startMenuItem.Enable() // Enable "Start" button if server is paused
        stopMenuItem.Disable() // Disable "Stop" button if server is paused
    } else if isServerRunning {
        startMenuItem.Disable() // Disable "Start" button if server is running
        stopMenuItem.Enable()   // Enable "Stop" button if server is running
    } else {
        startMenuItem.Enable() // Enable "Start" button if the server is not running
        stopMenuItem.Disable() // Disable "Stop" button if the server is not running
    }

    // Update the status and connected devices info
    updateServerStatus()
    updateConnectedDevices()
}

// Start the WebSocket server and clipboard monitoring
func startServer() {
    if isServerRunning {
        fmt.Println("[INFO] Server is already running")
        sendNotification("Running", "Server is already running")
        return
    }

    isServerRunning = true
    fmt.Println("[INFO] Starting server and clipboard monitoring")

    // Reinitialize channels
    stopMonitoring = make(chan bool)
    serverDone = make(chan bool)
    serverShutdown = make(chan bool)

    // Start WebSocket server and clipboard monitoring in separate goroutines
    go startWebSocketServer()
    go monitorClipboardChanges()

    // Optionally open QR page after server starts
    openQRCodePage()
}

// Stop the clipboard monitoring (pause)
func stopServer() {
    if !isServerRunning {
        fmt.Println("[INFO] Server is not running")
        return
    }

    paused = true // Set the flag to paused
    fmt.Println("[INFO] Pausing server and clipboard monitoring")

    // Send stop signal to clipboard monitoring
    stopMonitoring <- true
    sendNotification("Paused", "Clipboard syncing paused")
}

// Resume clipboard monitoring
func resumeServer() {
    if !isServerRunning || !paused {
        fmt.Println("[INFO] Server is already running or not paused")
        return
    }

    paused = false // Set the flag to resume
    fmt.Println("[INFO] Resuming clipboard monitoring")

    // Start clipboard monitoring again
    go monitorClipboardChanges()
    sendNotification("Resumed", "Clipboard syncing resumed")
}

// Start the WebSocket server
func startWebSocketServer() {
    // Get the specific local IP address
    ip := getLocalIP()
    if ip == "" {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Could not determine local IP address")
        return
    }

    // Start the WebSocket server on the local IP address
    address := fmt.Sprintf("%s:8080", ip)
    fmt.Printf("[INFO] Starting WebSocket server on ws://%s/ws\n", address)

    // Create a new WebSocket upgrader with custom origin check
    upgrader := websocket.Upgrader{
        CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
            return true
        },
    }

    // Create a new HTTP multiplexer and handle WebSocket connections
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)

        // Handle WebSocket upgrade errors
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("[ERROR] WebSocket upgrade error:", err)
            return
        }
        go handleClient(conn)
        defer conn.Close()

        clientsMutex.Lock()
        clients[conn] = true
        clientsMutex.Unlock()

        // Update the number of connected devices
        updateConnectedDevices()

        // Send a notification when a new device connects
        fmt.Printf("[INFO] Client connected. Total clients: %d\n", len(clients))
        sendNotification("Device Connected", "Total devices: "+fmt.Sprint(len(clients)))

        // Listen for client disconnects and remove them from the clients map
        for {
            _, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                clientsMutex.Lock()
                delete(clients, conn)
                clientsMutex.Unlock()
                fmt.Printf("message: %s\n", message)
                // Update the number of connected devices when a client disconnects
                updateConnectedDevices()

                fmt.Printf("[INFO] Client disconnected. Total clients: %d\n", len(clients))
                sendNotification("Device Disconnected", "Total devices: "+fmt.Sprint(len(clients)))
                break
            }
        }
    })

    // Create a new HTTP server to handle WebSocket connections
    httpServer = &http.Server{Addr: address, Handler: mux}
    err := httpServer.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] WebSocket server error:", err)
    }
}

// Monitor clipboard changes and broadcast new content to clients
func monitorClipboardChanges() {
    lastClipboardContent = readClipboard()

    for {
        select {
        case <-stopMonitoring:
            fmt.Println("[INFO] Clipboard monitoring paused")
            return
        default:
            if paused {
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // Just wait when paused
                continue
            }

            currentContent := readClipboard()
            if currentContent != lastClipboardContent {
                fmt.Printf("[INFO] Clipboard updated locally: %s\n", currentContent)
                broadcastClipboard(currentContent, "local", nil)
                lastClipboardContent = currentContent
            }
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}

// Handle client WebSocket communication
func handleClient(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        fmt.Println("[INFO] Client interacted")
        _, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("[ERROR] Failed to read message from client: %v\n", err)
            break
        }

        content := string(message)
        fmt.Printf("[INFO] Clipboard received from client: %s\n", content)

        if content != lastClipboardContent {
            err = clipboard.WriteAll(content)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("[ERROR] Failed to write to clipboard: %v\n", err)
                sendNotification("Clipboard Sync Error", "Failed to update clipboard.")
            } else {
                fmt.Println("[INFO] Clipboard successfully updated from client.")
                lastClipboardContent = content

                // Set the clipboard update source as "server"
                broadcastClipboard(content, "server", conn)
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println("[INFO] Ignored duplicate clipboard content.")
        }
    }
}

// Broadcast clipboard updates to all connected clients except the source
func broadcastClipboard(content, source string, sourceConn *websocket.Conn) {
    if source == "server" {
        fmt.Println("[INFO] Skipping broadcast for server-originated update.")
        return
    }

    clientsMutex.Lock()
    defer clientsMutex.Unlock()

    for client := range clients {
        if client == sourceConn {
            continue // Skip broadcasting to the source client
        }

        err := client.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(content))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("[ERROR] Failed to send message to client: %v\n", err)
            client.Close()
            delete(clients, client)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("[INFO] Broadcasted clipboard update to %d clients\n", len(clients))
}

var qrRouteRegistered = false

func openQRCodePage() {
    // Register the /qr route only once
    if !qrRouteRegistered {
        ip := getLocalIP()
        wsURL := fmt.Sprintf("ws://%s:8080/ws", ip)
        qrCode, err := qrcode.Encode(wsURL, qrcode.Medium, 256)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("[ERROR] Failed to generate QR code:", err)
            return
        }

        // Register the route for QR page
        http.HandleFunc("/qr", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
            fmt.Fprintf(w, `HTML_CONTENT`, wsURL, base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(qrCode))
        })

        // Mark the route as registered
        qrRouteRegistered = true
    }

    // Start the QR server in a new goroutine to serve the page
    go startQRCodeServer()

    // Open the QR code page in the browser using a unique URL path
    ip := "localhost"
    err := exec.Command(getBrowserCommand(), "/c", "start", fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:3000/qr", ip)).Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Failed to open QR code page:", err)
    }
}

// Start an HTTP server on port 3000 to serve the QR code page
func startQRCodeServer() {
    httpServer := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":3000", // Listen on port 3000
        Handler: nil,     // Use default mux
    }

    fmt.Println("[INFO] Starting HTTP server on http://localhost:3000")
    if err := httpServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] HTTP server error:", err)
    }
}

// Utility to get the default browser command based on OS
func getBrowserCommand() string {
    switch runtime.GOOS {
    case "windows":
        return "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
    case "darwin":
        return "open"
    default:
        return "xdg-open"
    }
}

// Utility to read clipboard content
func readClipboard() string {
    content, err := clipboard.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Error reading clipboard:", err)
        return ""
    }
    return content
}

// Utility to get local IP address (WLAN adapter)
func getLocalIP() string {
    interfaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Failed to retrieve network interfaces:", err)
        return "127.0.0.1"
    }

    for _, iface := range interfaces {
        // Check if the interface is up and not a loopback interface
        if iface.Flags&net.FlagUp != 0 && iface.Flags&net.FlagLoopback == 0 {
            addrs, err := iface.Addrs()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("[ERROR] Failed to retrieve addresses for interface:", iface.Name, err)
                continue
            }

            for _, addr := range addrs {
                // Parse the address and check if it's IPv4
                if ipNet, ok := addr.(*net.IPNet); ok && ipNet.IP.To4() != nil {
                    // Ensure we get the Wi-Fi adapter's IP
                    if strings.Contains(iface.Name, "Wi-Fi") || strings.Contains(iface.Name, "wlan") {
                        return ipNet.IP.String()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Fallback to localhost if no valid IP is found
    return "127.0.0.1"
}

// Utility to get tray icon (reads icon file and returns it as byte slice)
func getIcon() []byte {
    // Load the icon from a file (ensure the path to the icon is correct)
    iconPath := "icon.ico" // Replace with your actual file path

    iconFile, err := os.Open(iconPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Failed to load icon:", err)
        return nil
    }
    defer iconFile.Close()

    // Read the icon file into a byte slice
    iconBytes, err := io.ReadAll(iconFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Failed to read icon:", err)
        return nil
    }

    return iconBytes
}

// Send a notification if notifications are enabled
func sendNotification(title, message string) {
    if notificationsEnabled {
        err := beeep.Notify(title, message, "clipylogo.png")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("[ERROR] Unable to send notification: %v\n", err)
        }
    }
}

// Function to toggle notifications on or off
func toggleNotifications() {
    if notificationsEnabled {
        notificationsEnabled = false
        notificationsMenuItem.SetTitle("Enable Notifications")
        sendNotification("Notifications Disabled", "Notifications have been turned off.")
    } else {
        notificationsEnabled = true
        notificationsMenuItem.SetTitle("Disable Notifications")
        sendNotification("Notifications Enabled", "Notifications have been turned on.")
    }
}

// Cleanup on exit
func onExit() {
    // Stop clipboard monitoring by sending stop signal
    stopMonitoring <- true

    // Wait for server shutdown signal (confirm server is stopped)
    <-serverDone

    // Close WebSocket connections (close each client connection)
    clientsMutex.Lock()
    for client := range clients {
        err := client.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("[ERROR] Failed to close client connection: %v\n", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("[INFO] Client connection closed.")
        }
    }
    clientsMutex.Unlock()

    // Close the HTTP server (shuts down WebSocket server as well)
    if httpServer != nil {
        err := httpServer.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("[ERROR] Failed to close HTTP server: %v\n", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("[INFO] HTTP server stopped successfully.")
        }
    }

    // Signal that the server is fully stopped
    serverShutdown <- true
    fmt.Println("[INFO] Server stopped successfully.")

}



The program concurrently reads messages from two goroutines.  One of the goroutines discards the messages.  Fix by merging the loop in handleClient to the loop in the http handler.  Note that concurrent reads are not supported by Gorilla.

@CeriseLimón thanks for you response. I got it, the concurrent read are not supported in gorilla. I've fixed it by shifting my handleClient inside the startWebSocketServer. It works now. Thanks!

Even if Gorilla supported concurrent reads, the application would still have an error.  One of the goroutines reads and discards messages.
